# When will the no-longer-experimental HTTP2 module be included in updates for 16.04?

Tags: updates, apache2

I know the release notes for 16.04 listed the Apache HTTP/2 module as being left off because the module was marked as experimental in the Apache project, but that label has been dropped from the [associated module page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html) since at least [June 25th](https://web.archive.org/web/20170625070856/https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html).  Given this information, how long do modules like this generally take to be added into the mainstream updates?

Comment: See this comment, maybe file a bug for 16.04 to get more definitive response.. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1658469/comments/10